# Relational Algebra: set theoretic definitions for typical operations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relation-algebra

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) has set theoretic definitions of relational algebra used in databases.  The typical set operations are missing and I'm trying to piece them together.  **Does anyone know how to define the $\cup, \cap, -, X^C$ set operations over the relation?**

For example, the relation $R$ or *table* is defined as a set of $t_n$ tuples, where each tuple has $z$ attributes and $p$ values, where a single attribute can have many values.
$$
R = \{t_0,...,t_n\}, t_x = ((a_1,v_{1}), ...,(a_z,v_{p}))
$$
All the attributes for a tuple.
$$
A(t) = \{a : (a,h) \in t\}
$$
The attributes for each tuple in the relation must be the same.
$$
TT = R \times R
$$
$$
\forall x,y \in TT (A(x) = A(y))
$$

Projection over attributes is defined:
$$
\Pi_{a_1, ...,a_n}( R ) = \{  \ t[a_1,...,a_n] : \ t \in R \ \}
$$
$$ t[a_1,...,a_n] = \{ \ ( a', v ) \ | \ ( a', v ) \in t, \ a' \in \{a_1,...,a_n \} \}
$$

Selection:
$$
\sigma_\varphi(R) = \{ \ t : t \in R, \ \varphi(t) \ \}
$$

I'm assuming the set operations can all be defined with union and complement.  I think the attributes need to be in correspondence with integers, so the relational table $R$ can be converted into a Cartesian product $A_1 \times ... \times A_n$, then converted back to it's relational representation $R$.  I'm interested in what folks with more experience define these as.

Comment: Not very clear... from [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Set_operators): "The relational algebra uses set union, set difference, and Cartesian product from set theory, but adds additional constraints to these operators." So, the basic set-theoretic "algebraic" operations are already there and we use them to define the specific "relational" operations.

Comment: Please do not [cross post to multiple sites](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148631/71613). My comments on your other post explain that your question is based on some misconceptions & that the Wikipedia article is unclear & that we can nevertheless infer what the missing definitions of tuple, relation & operators are, but since you're reading an unclear presentation & give inconsistent versions of the missing definitions, why? Find or construct a clear presentation--one that defines its terms before using them. PS Read published reviewed/edited sources, not Wikipedia.

Comment: And yes, a *binary* relation is a set of *pairs*: $R = \{ (a_1,v_1), \ldots, (a_n,v_n) \}$ where each $a_i$ may occur more than once. Example, the relation (Country, Town): { (GB, London), (GB, Manchester), ... (France,Paris), ... }

Comment: In set theory everything is a set; thus, the intersection of two relations $R_1 \cap R_2$ is the set of common elements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I redefined the tuple and relation because they were wrong.  I think you're correct, $R_1 \cap R_2$ etc is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

These operations are in their standard set theoretic form.  $R_1 x R_2$, where the operation are $x \{\cap, \cup, C\}$.

Comment: There's no complement in relational algebras as normally understood as a basis for computation. ∪, ∩ & − yes. Research relational model "safety". PS Beware that your use of formulas is sloppy in an ungrammatical way, particularly regarding quantification & scope of names, so that you are not actually saying things that make sense, and this is an impediment to understanding & communication. Writing should be clear after formulas are mechanically translated to natural language.